# How to configure unhandled-rejections for jest in bazel

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, bazel, bazel-rules-nodejs

The below configuration in npmrc file suppresses the error for unhandledPromiseRejection after migration from node 14 to node 16.

**.npmrc**
`node-options="--unhandled-rejections=none"`

But in bazel using jest_test, unsure where to configure this. Can we do it with `jest_test` or `package.json` or `jest.config.js`

How and what is the appropriate way to do this?

tried to import `.npmrc` file in `npm_install` of `rules_nodejs` library with version 5.x version. But it is just copying registry url and ignoring other configs.

Is that a permission issue or if rules_nodejs npmrc is getting overridden? or anything else i am missing here?

What is the right way to suppress this error in jest_test in bazel with jest_cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handled from **jest.config.ts**

`setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/.jest/handleErrors.js'],`

**handleErrors.js**

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', reason => {
  return;
});
```